# Looking for SQL Server query optimization

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I have this query which is running very slow in SQL Server. Please suggest to optimize it to run faster.

- `TABLE_A` has 100'000'000 rows
- `TABLE_B` has   1'000'000 rows

Both tables have nonclustered index on `ID`, `Modify_Date` and `Source` column.

Query:

```
Insert into TABLE_A       
  select * from RABLE_B B
  Where NOT Exists (Select 1 
                    From TABLE_A A
                    Where B.ID = A.ID
                      And B.Modify_Date = A.Modify_Date
                      And B.Source = A.Source)
```

Comment: If you don't have already: add a **good** clustering key to both tables!

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT  INTO TABLE_A
        SELECT  B.*
        FROM    TABLE_B B
                LEFT JOIN TABLE_A A ON B.ID = A.ID
                                   AND B.Modify_Date = A.Modify_Date
                                   AND B.Source = A.Source
        WHERE   A.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Multi join under left is also running slow.

Comment: Why you think that the query I Mentioned was running slow and the query you have updated will be faster.

Comment: Then you should create an index on [Modify_Date] and [Source]

Comment: I already mentioned that indexes are already created.

Why you think that the query I Mentioned was running slow and the query you have updated will be faster. –

Answer (score 0):

Changing your tables from heap tables to clustered tables on `ID` seems like it should help. If `ID` is not unique than making a compound clustered index on all three columns would help with join speed since the data from the table would be ordered on the pages based on the three columns.

The tradeoff that you take by making the clustered key a compound key is inserts and updates will take a little longer. However if the tables structure has been designed well and insert and update statements are also designed well this is a tradeoff worth taking.

Finally if this table does not have a primary key it would be good to minimally add one since you are looking up all the columns on `Table_B` to insert into `Table_A`. Adding a primary key should help the optimizer not have to scan the table but instead use a seek to find the data.